# Unable to resolve @RestController annotation in spring 2.0.3

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am making a new springboot- maven project. The compiler is unable to resolve `@RestController` when I use below `pom.xml`

```
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

However, when I change the version to 1.5.13, the compiler is able to resolve `@RestController`

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I want to be using the latest version of spring boot, and use `@RestController`.

Comment: is it from `IDE` or you also tried from `cmd`

Comment: its from eclipse, but that shoudnt be the cause I suppose

Comment: can you try `mvn -X clean install`

Comment: tried didnt work

Comment: please post the debug output that you got.

Answer (score 3):

`@RestController` doesn't come from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`, it comes from `org.springframework:spring-web`. Different versions of spring-boot-starter-web must probably have some transient dependency that provides it, but it's a bad practice to rely on it. If you use `@RestController` in your code, you should explicitly require the artifact that provides it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

since i can't add a comment, i think the maven config is not your problem, check your @Configuration and @SpringBootApplication classes and their path scanning settings

another problem you could have: maybe one of your other dependencies still depends on springboot 1.5, you have to have a clean springboot 2.0 classpath

i run in problems like this as well, so keep on diggin, you'll find it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat a similar issue and it was because I named my class **RestController**. Once I renamed it **Controller**, I could import the @RestController packages without issues.